# How can I initialize View Again in SwiftUI?

Tags: memory-management, struct, swiftui, navigationlink

I’m using SwfitUI in my project and I have a NavigationView and List. I’m clicking cell after open the detail view and click navigation back button. I want to remove view (it’s struct, in SwiftUI) after click navigation back button. Because if I click the same cell or button again, it isn’t initialize new view, it’s shows old view. I want to do refresh this view. How do I do?

My FirstView Struct is:

```
struct FirstView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FirstViewModel

    var body: some View {
        List(self.viewModel.objects, id: \.id) { object in
            ZStack {
                DetailViewCell(object: object)
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewBuilder.make(object)) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My DetailView Struct is:

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.mainBackground.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Image("Square")
                    Image(self.viewModel.currentImage)
                }
                Text(self.viewModel.currentText)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.viewModel.pressedPlayOrPauseButton()
                }, label: {
                    Image(self.viewModel.isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play").foregroundColor(Color("Orange"))
                }).padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, I go to the detail by clicking a cell in FirstView. Then I come back with the back button. I click on a cell again to go to the details, but a new view does not open. It shows the old view.

Before I forget, My Builder Class is:

```
final class DetailViewBuilder {
    static func make(object: Something) -> DetailView {

        let viewModel = DetailViewModel(object: object)
        let view = DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)

        return view
    }
}
```

Note: If I will use Sheet Presented, It's working. It's creating new View. But I want to use NavigationLink. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to defer your destination creation in your builder, and the `@ViewBuilder` is a good instrument for this.

It can be used the following wrapper for to create real destination only in when `body` will be rendered (ie. explicitly in time of navigation clicked in your case)

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct DeferView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        content()          // << everything is created here
    }
}
```

and now your builder

```
final class DetailViewBuilder {
    static func make(object: Something) -> some View {
        DeferView {
           DetailView(viewModel: DetailViewModel(object: object))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Really @ViewBuilder is a good solution.

Comment: this is a great answer! it also solved my problem when destination view gets created multiple times as my current view gets refreshed multiple times

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on why this works? Why doesn't this all get executed as usual, right away?

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI initialises `NavigationView` links eagerly, so you can't rely on their initialiser to run every time. If you write a custom init() for DetailView

```
    init(viewModel: DetailViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    print("Initialising \(self)")
}
```

you'll see the line print out for every navigation link when your FirstView loads.

Depending on what you want to do you could implement a `.onAppear {}` closure on the DetailView which will change the data when the view appears. It's a little tricky to try to offer implementation examples since I'm unsure what your goal here is specifically.

There's some interesting discussion of this at: 
https://www.notion.so/Lazy-Loading-Data-with-SwiftUI-and-Combine-70546ec6aca3481f80d104cd1f10a31a

Do any of the suggestions here look like they could be relevant to what you're trying to do?