# SwiftUI onAppear called multiple times because of NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI onAppear gets called multiple times when inside of a navigation link. In the example I have provided, it gets called 5 times. This also triggers its StateObject initializer to get called 5 times as well. If you comment the Navigation Link out, it performs as expected.

This has been tested with both Xcode 12 GM and Xcode 12.2 with iOS 14 GM and iOS 14.2 beta 1. Also filed as feedback FB8721761.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Color.red, label: {
            ImageView()
                .frame(width: 166.66, height: 250)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        })
    }
}

struct ImageView: View{
    @StateObject private var downloader = Downloaded(url: URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/TnOeov4w0sTtV2gqICqIxVi74V.jpg")!)

    var body: some View{
        Rectangle()
            .onAppear{
                print("Appeared")
            }
    }
}

class Downloaded: ObservableObject{
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let url: URL

    init(url: URL){
        self.url = url
        download()
    }

    func download(){
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
                print("Finished downloading")
            }, receiveValue: {_ in})
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an @State boolean variable to track whether onAppear has already been before, by using an if condition inside the onAppear

Comment: Yes and it shows that its only called once, however if you check the debugger thats not the case.

Comment: `onAppear` seems to be called multiple times on several occasions. For example, presenting a ProgressView causes `onAppear` to be called for the presenting view, when the ProgressView is declared in a ZStack on top of the presenting view - and no other changes to any observed values happen.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a feedback with Apple and this has been resolved in iOS 14.2 beta 3.

Comment: Hi - I still see this reproing with iOS 14.5. Are you seeing this fixed?

Comment: This is working correctly on 14.5.1. I tested with an iPhone 12 as well as Xcode 12.5 simulator. No issues.

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon I still got this problem. I'm using Xcode 12.5, Simulator iPhone Mini iOS 14.5. The hierarchy of views is: `WindowGroup { TabView { NavigationView { TopStoriesView() }` My TopStoriesView.onAppear() is called 2 times on app start.

Comment: Well my app has to support iOS 13 thanks Apple for back supporting bug fixing (not)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works for me. There should be only one root `NavigationView`, if you put parent and child `NavigationView` then `onAppear` called multiple times