# Popping views using SceneDelegate.toView()

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a UI where you can navigate/push views like this:
AView -> BView -> CView -> DView

I want to pop a couple of views (get to BView from DView) instead of placing a new view (BView) on top of existing stack and I found the way to do this:

> (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as?
> SceneDelegate)?.toBView()

What I don't understand is why does it call CView's init() when I try to return from DView to BView?

Here's the output i get in debug console:

```
AView init
BView init
CView init
DView init
contract.
button pressed
BView init
**CView init**
```

Why does it call **CView's init()** and how to avoid this behaviour?

AView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AView: View {
    
    init() {
        print("AView init")
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: BView()) {
                    Text("This is View A, now go to View B.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BView: View {
    init() {
        print("BView init")
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CView()) {
                Text("This is View B, now go to View C.")
        }
    }
}

struct CView: View {
    
    init() {
        print("CView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DView()) {
                Text("This is View C, now go to View D.")
        }
    }
}

struct DView: View {
    init() {
        print("DView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("button pressed")
            (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.toBView()

        },
               label: {
            Text("Back!")
        })

    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let aView =     AView()
        
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: AView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    
    func toBView() {
        let bView = BView()
        window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: bView)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not wrong. If you start your app and display AView you will see in the console that it prints init from A and B.

It's because BView() is already initialized in your AView, even though you haven't activated the NavigationLink.

```
NavigationLink(destination: BView()) {
```

So this behavior is not specific to your pop back action, happens already at the beginning. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61743337/11878069) solution from Asperi regarding multiple init() aswell, if you are concerned about calling init() more than once