# iOS 14 SwiftUI Selecting Textfield Calls Parent View's .onAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, onappear

I call to hide and show my TabBar in my view's .onAppear, this functionality worked fine in iOS 13 and Xcode 11. However, after updating to Xcode 12 and iOS 14 whenever I select a TextField in a child view which was presented via NavigationLink, the parent's .onAppear function is called. This results in unwanted calls, particularly calls that hide/show my app's TabBar.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64065611/12299030? If now then provide your code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Asperi Yes it did solve my problem.