# NavigationLink Bug

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have this two views:

```
import SwiftUI
import QGrid

struct CategoriasCanales: View {
    @Binding var logueado:Bool
    @ObservedObject var categorias = CargarCategoriasCanales()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.categorias.listaCategoriasCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:VerCanales(categoria: item.categoryID)){
                    Text(item.categoryName).frame(width:400, height:50)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
import SwiftUI
import QGrid

struct VerCanales: View {
    
   
    private var categoria: String
    @ObservedObject private var canales: CargarCanales
  
    init(categoria: String) {
        print(categoria)
            self.categoria = categoria
            self.canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:PlayerVersa(canalID: item.streamID)){
                    Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
            
                }
          
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I enter the "CategoriasCanales" view, it runs the init of the "VerCanales" view a number of times equal to the number of categories.

I am new to SwiftUI, in DART for example, the Print() in the ChannelView init would only print the category that I am sending as a parameter, not all categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationLink` creates destination view in place of initialization, so you see called `VerCanales.init` as many as `self.categorias.listaCategoriasCanales` count.

I assume you wanted to defer creation of `VerCanales`: (used `DeferView` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61242931/12299030)

```
NavigationLink(destination:DeferView { VerCanales(categoria: item.categoryID) }){
    Text(item.categoryName).frame(width:400, height:50)
}
```

*Note: you don't need second `NavigationView` in `VerCanales`, only one navigation view should be in navigation stack and there is that one already in CategoriasCanales*

Answer (score 1):

Try using onAppear instead of init

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:PlayerVersa(canalID: item.streamID)){
                    Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
            
                }
          
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            print(categoria)
            self.categoria = categoria
            self.canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can't use the .onAppear() since I need to capture the variables before initializing to be able to pass them as argument of the ObservedObject